# Right bit shift in body of lambda used as a template argument doesn't compile on GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++20, compiler-bug

GCC doesn't compile this code, while other compilers (clang, msvc) do

```cpp
template<auto T>
struct S { };

int main() {
  S<[]{int x,y; x<<y;}> s1; // compiles fine
  S<[]{int x,y; x>>y;}> s2; // error
}
```

error:

```text
error: expected ';' before '>>' token
      |     S<[]{int x,y; x>>y;}> s2;
      |                    ^~
      |                    ;
```

However when I explicitly call `operator>>`, GCC accepts it

```cpp
struct S2 {
  void operator>>(S2 arg) { }
};
S<[]{S2 x,y; x.operator>>(y);}> s2; // compiles
```

It also does compile when I move the lambda definition outside of template parameter list

```cpp
auto lam = []{int x,y; x>>y;}; 
S<lam> s; // compiles
```

Is it a compiler bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

g++ is actually correct here. From `[temp.names]/3` ([C++20 Draft N4860](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf)):

> When a name is considered to be a *template-name*, and it is followed by a `<`, the `<` is always taken as the delimiter of a *template-argument-list* and never as the less-than operator. When parsing a *template-argument-list*, the first non-nested `>` is taken as the ending delimiter rather than a greater-than operator. Similarly, the first non-nested `>>` is treated as two consecutive but distinct `>` tokens, the first of which is taken as the end of the *template-argument-list* and completes the *template-id*. [*Note*: The second `>` token produced by this replacement rule may terminate an enclosing *template-id* construct or it may be part of a different construct (e.g., a cast). — end note] [*Example*:
>
> ```cpp
> template<int i> class X { /* ... */ };
> X< 1>2 > x1;                            // syntax error
> X<(1>2)> x2;                            // OK
>
> template<class T> class Y { /* ... */ };
> Y<X<1>> x3;                             // OK, same as Y<X<1> > x3;
> Y<X<6>>1>> x4;                          // syntax error
> Y<X<(6>>1)>> x5;                        // OK
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

The `>>` is treated as two `>` tokens. You can wrap it in brackets to enforce what you are trying to do if you want.

```
template<auto T>
struct S { };

int main() {
  S<[]{int x,y; (x>>y);}> s2; // now compiles fine
}
```

Note: it may be that both accepting or rejecting is correct, since it's a bit vague what is meant by *nested*. See comments.

Comment: I am not so sure this is a correct reading of the standard, though. It seems to hinge on a rather… not *indisputably* correct interpretation of the admittedly vague term ‘non-nested’. (Why should one not expect the curly brackets delimiting the lambda body to ‘nest’ the token if plain parentheses do?) I’d rather consider this a case of underspecification, if not a compiler bug.

Comment: @user3840170, I tried looking up the definition of _nested_, but could not find one, other than the footnote: _A > that encloses the type-id of a dynamic_­cast, static_­cast, reinterpret_­cast or const_­cast, or which encloses the template-arguments of a subsequent template-id, is considered nested for the purpose of this description._ I'd assume that nested would mean another `<` in this context. Their examples do specify using `(` and `)` to prevent the error though. It's definitely rather strange. It may be that it's okay to accept or reject, due to the ambiguity.

Comment: Footnotes and examples are non-normative AFAIK, though I think it’s okay to use them for disambiguation, as in this case… although they don’t seem to disambiguate *enough* here.

Comment: @user3840170, I added a note to the end of my answer. It is definitely an odd case.

Comment: @user3840170 Looks like `()` and `[]` don't require extra brackets on any compiler, only GCC requires ones for `{}`. Every compiler requires  extra brackets for `<>`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f728b0941c8b67c0
Tested it with gcc 12.2; clang 15.0.0; msvc v19.33.